# restart local computer from python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, shutdown, restart

Is there any way to make the computer a Python program is running on restart? Generic solution is good, but in particular I'm on windows.

Comment: Not windows, but on linux it's as easy as os.system("reboot"). Presuming you have the correct privileges.

Comment: Don't recommend `os.system`. It's been deprecated. @Claudiu: Use `subprocess`.

Comment: @A A: No, it has not been deprecated, and for something trivial like this it works just fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no generic way of doing this, afaik.

For Windows, you need to access the Win32 API. Like so:

```
  import win32api
  win32api.InitiateSystemShutdown()
```

The win32api module is a part of [pywin32](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32/).

For linux/os x, I guess calling the "reboot" command is the easiest.

```
import os
os.system('reboot now')
```

Or something like that.

(Note to downvoters: `os.system()` has *not* been deprecated. The text is "The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function." For simple cases like this, when you aren't interested in retrieving the results, nor in multiprocessing, `os.system()` works just fine).

Comment: I did not vote you down, however, using an an external module (win32api) to reboot a machine, which could be rebooted directly with wmi using `wmic` is so and so. The use of os.system I do not care about.

Comment: @Anders: "WMIC.exe is only available under Windows XP Professional, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008." So, no. Bad idea.

Comment: It's available on other systems also, for example, Windows 7. I don't know if it's included in a SP for Windows XP Home, very well could be.

Comment: It seems not. So if you know it's available on your system, then that would work. As a generic solution it's less ideal.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you just call the [shutdown](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true) command using subprocess?

Answer (score 9):

You could reboot a Windows system by using: `os.system("shutdown -t 0 -r -f")`

Example:

```
import os
print("REBOOTING")
os.system("shutdown -t 0 -r -f")
```

Change the number in front of -t to change the number of seconds before shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

**There is nothing in the standard library that would directly allow you to do this, and I am unaware of any modules that provide a cross platform method, but if you are on Windows and don't want to install anything (like the win32api) then you could use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) default module and interact with the WinAPI directly.**

You could use the [`ExitWindowsEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868(VS.85).aspx) function to restart the computer (it is almost the same as my other answer [How to shudown a computer using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039845/how-to-shudown-a-computer-using-python/50824776#50824776); however the hexadecimal value has to be changed to restart and not shutdown).

---

**Process:**

First you need ctypes:

```
import ctypes
```

Next get the `user32.dll` as described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868(VS.85).aspx):

> DLL | User32.dll

So:

```
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
```

Next you need to call the `ExitWindowsEx()` function and insert the correct hexadecimal values:

```
user32.ExitWindowsEx(0x00000002, 0x00000000)
```

The first argument (`0x00000002`) shuts down the system and then restarts (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868(VS.85).aspx)).

The second argument (`0x00000000`) gives a reason to be logged by the system.  A complete list can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376885(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

**Complete Code:**

```
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
user32.ExitWindowsEx(0x00000002, 0x00000000)
```

---

*About `os.system()` method on Windows:*

The win32api or ctypes answers both will execute silently.  `os.system("shutdown -t 0 -r -f")` will leave a message saying "You are about to be signed out in less than a minute" which may be undesirable in some cases.

A file alongside the script called `shutdown.bat`/`shutdown.exe`/`shutdown.cmd` will cause the command `shutdown -t 0 -r -f` to break, calling that file and not the system command.  The same goes for described `wmic.exe` above.

---

**As a side note:** I built [WinUtils](https://pypi.org/project/WinUtils/) (Windows only) which simplifies this a bit, however it should be faster (and does not require Ctypes) since it is built in C.

<sup>**Example:**</sup>

```
import WinUtils
WinUtils.Restart(WinUtils.SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_OTHER)
```

Comment: Cygwin python's `ctypes` module lacks `WinDLL` function. I ended up doing it with cffi.