# How to shutdown a computer using Python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, shutdown

I've written a Python script which should eventually shutdown the computer.

This line is a part of it :

```
os.system("shutdown /p")
```

It makes some sort of a shutdown but remains on the turn-on Windows control pannel (where the user can switch the computer users).

Is there a way to fully shutdown the computer?

I've tried other `os.system("shutdown ___")` methods with no success.

Is there another method which might help?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Python, as `shutdown /p` is simply sent to the system as a terminal command. Please specify your OS version, as the options can vary.

Comment: Yes of course. But my question is whether there's a way using Python modules maybe? or another way?

And I need to run the program on several computers, so the OS version is not the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

```
import os
os.system('shutdown -s')
```

This will work for you.

Comment: One problem with this is that it leaves a message saying `"You are about to be signed out in less than a minute"`.  Another is that if someone places a batch script with the name `shutdown.bat` with the script it will not work, it's also a security hazard since that file will be executed.  [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) should now be used over `os.system()`.

Comment: You can avoid that message - os.system('shutdown -s -t 0')

Comment: How do I skip the tasks are open window promt? and force shutdown?

Answer (score 14):

For Linux:

```
import os
os.system('sudo shutdown now')
```

or: if you want immediate shutdown without `sudo` prompt for password, use the following for Ubuntu and similar distro's:

```
os.system('systemctl poweroff')
```

Comment: [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) should now be used over `os.system()`.

Answer (score 5):

Using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) you could use the [ExitWindowsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868(VS.85).aspx) function to shutdown the computer.

Description from MSDN:

> Logs off the interactive user, shuts down the system, or shuts down and restarts the system.

---

**First some code:**

```
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')

user32.ExitWindowsEx(0x00000008, 0x00000000)
```

**Now the explanation line by line:**

- Get the ctypes library
- The `ExitWindowsEx` is provided by the `user32.dll` and needs to be loaded via `WinDLL()`
- Call the `ExitWindowsEx()` function and pass the necessary parameters.

**Parameters:**

All the arguments are hexadecimals.

*The first argument I selected:*

> shuts down the system and turns off the power. The system must support the power-off feature.

There are many other possible functions see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868(VS.85).aspx) for a complete list.

*The second argument:*

The second argument *must* give a reason for the shutdown, which is logged by the system. In this case I set it for `Other issue` but there are many to choose from.  See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376885(v=vs.85).aspx) for a complete list.

**Making it cross platform:**

This can be combined with other methods to make it cross platform.  For example:

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':

    import ctypes
    user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
    user32.ExitWindowsEx(0x00000008, 0x00000000)

else:

    import os
    os.system('sudo shutdown now')
```

---

*This is a Windows dependant function (although Linux/Mac will have an equivalent), but is a better solution than calling `os.system()` since a batch script called `shutdown.bat` will not conflict with the command (and causing a security hazard in the meantime).*

**In addition it does not bother users with a message saying `"You are about to be signed out in less than a minute"` like `shutdown -s` does, but executes silently.**

As  a side note use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) over `os.system()` (see [Difference between subprocess.Popen and os.system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system))

---

**As a side note:** I built [WinUtils](https://github.com/Simon3335/WinUtils) (Windows only) which simplifies this a bit, however it should be faster (and does not require Ctypes) since it is built in C.

<sup>**Example:**</sup>

```
import WinUtils
WinUtils.Shutdown(WinUtils.SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_OTHER)
```

Comment: I would prefer poweroff or init 6

Answer (score 5):

[Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) recommends using subprocess instead of os.system. It intends to replace old modules like os.system and others.

So, use this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["shutdown", "-s"])
```

And for linux users `-s` is not required, they can just use

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["shutdown"])
```

Answer (score 4):

The only variant that really workes for me without any problem is:

```
import os
os.system('shutdown /p /f')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet:

```
import os 

shutdown = input("Do you wish to shutdown your computer ? (yes / no): ") 

if shutdown == 'no': 
    exit() 
else: 
    os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

This Python code may do the deed:

```
import os
os.system('sudo shutdown -h now')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample to power off **Windows**:

```
import os

os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
```

---

Here's a sample to power off **Linux** (by root permission):

```
import os

os.system("shutdown now -h")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wish, winapi can be used.

```
import win32api,win32security,winnt
win32security.AdjustTokenPrivilege(win32security.OpenProcessHandle(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(),win32security.ADJUST_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY),False,[(win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None,winnt.SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME),winnt.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLE)])
win32api.InitateSystemShutdown(None,"Text",second,Force_Terminate_Apps_as_boolean,Restart_as_boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

pip install schedule

In case you also want to schedule it:

```
import schedule
import time
import os

when= "20:11"
print("The computer will be shutdown at " + when + "")

def job():
    os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")

schedule.every().day.at(when).do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows case, using `os.system("shutdown /p")` works but sometimes makes a quick flashing terminal window (see [this precise situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946618/how-to-call-a-shell-command-fom-pythonw-with-no-explorer-exe-running-without-a)).

In this case it's better to use `subprocess` with a process creation flag:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /p", creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```