# shell_exec not executing well

Tags: python, php, linux, ubuntu

I have a php code that is supposed to run a command(python code) in linux (specifically ubuntu)
The python code I have is the following:

```
import os
os.system("poweroff")
```

but.. when I run the php code that contains

```
shell_exec("python3 /var/www/html/main.py);
```

It doesn't works. My device doesn't shuts down.

Please can anybody help?

I have already tried running

```
exec("python3 /var/www/html/main.py);
```

but that didn't worked as well....

Comment: python script's command `poweroff`  might be wrong , see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039845/how-to-shutdown-a-computer-using-python

Comment: I have already seen those answers before posting my question.... And more over... When I run the python code from the terminal.. it works. Its just not working with PHP... Can you help about that?