# Is there a command in Python for instant shutdown on Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, shutdown

I want a function or a command that will instantly shutdown my laptop.

I am using windows 10.

I want the code to be like:

```py
command = input("what to do? ")
if command == "shutdown":
   shutdown()
```

That should shut down the system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shutdown a computer using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039845/how-to-shutdown-a-computer-using-python)

Comment: But that doesn't answer how to shutdown instantly

Comment: Pear gave me the code it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah that's easy in case of windows

windows has built in command `shutdown /s /t0` for instant shutdown

Code:

```py
import os

def shutdown():
    #shutdown /s -> shuts down the computer [but it takes time]
    #also shows message windows is going to be shutdown within a minute
    #to avoid this we use /t parameter time=0seconds /t0
    #command = shutdown /s /t0
    #execute to the shell
    os.system("shutdown /s /t0")

a = input("What to do?")

if a == "shutdown":
    shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should work:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
def shutdown():
    subprocess.run(shlex.split("shutdown /s"))
```

Quoting from https://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/109196:

> To shut down your computer, type shutdown /s. 
> To restart your computer, type shutdown /r. 
> To log off your computer type shutdown /l. 
> For a complete list of options type shutdown /?

Comment: But it doesn't shutdown instantly
The code that pear provided shutdown my pc instantly as i tried