# How to call a shell command fom pythonw (with no explorer.exe running) without a terminal window flashing?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, embedded, pythonw

I am running a Python program on Windows with:

- no `explorer.exe` running, no desktop, no start menu, typical for embedded computers. If you want to try, you can emulate this by killing `explorer.exe` in the Task manager ; note that I do it differently but out of topic here
- `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` to avoid a to have a `cmd.exe` terminal window

If you run `pythonw test.py` with

```
import os
os.system("shutdown /r /t 3600")
```

you will see a terminal window flashing during < 1 second.

Same problem with `subprocess.call(...)`.

Same problem with `subprocess.run(...)` like in [Is there a command in Python for instant shutdown on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342897/is-there-a-command-in-python-for-instant-shutdown-on-windows-10/67342923#67342923).

(Note: if explorer.exe is killed, you can call the Task Manager with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ESCAPE</kbd> and `Run` command to launch `pythonw test.py`)

**Question: How to call Windows tools like `shutdown` with 1) no explorer.exe 2) pythonw.exe,  without seeing a cmd.exe window flashing?**

Comment: @Mofi Tested now, it works with the creation flag indeed! I posted an answer, as "community wiki" since most of the content is from you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
import subprocess

# restart
subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /r /t 0", creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)

# power off
subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /p", creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

Context (pasted from @Mofi's comments):

`os.system` is declared as deprecated since more than 10 years and should not be used anymore at all. There is the `subprocess` module which gives a Python script writer the full control on Windows how an executable is run by calling the Windows kernel library function `CreateProcess` without or with a `STARTUPINFO` structure.

`os.system()` calls the system function which on Windows results in calling `CreateProcess` with `%ComSpec%` (defined with `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` expanding usually to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`) with the option `/c` (run command line and close) and the command line passed as argument to `os.system` appended as additional arguments for `cmd.exe`.

In this case `cmd.exe` searches for a file with name `shutdown` in the current directory and next in the directories as listed in local environment variable `PATH` with no file extension at all or with a file extension as listed in local environment variable `PATHEXT`. It hopefully finds in this case after several file system accesses `%SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe` and calls now `CreateProcess` to run this batch file with using the standard streams of `cmd.exe` and waiting for self-termination of `shutdown.exe` after which `cmd.exe` closes itself.

There can be used `os.environ` to get the string value of the environment variable `SystemRoot`. This directory path string can next be concatenated with the string `"\\System32\\shutdown.exe"` to get the fully qualified file name of the executable to run. It is very unlikely that the environment variable `SystemRoot` is not defined at all. That is possible only if a user explicitly deletes this environment variable in a command prompt window before starting in same command prompt window Python for interpreting a Python script.

There should be used the string `"C:\\Windows"` in case of `environ["SystemRoot"]` returns no string (or an empty string). However, it is advisable to check the existence of finally determined fully qualified file name of the Windows command SHUTDOWN and inform the user if the executable is not existing instead of a blind execution of this executable and hoping it really exists although this is most likely always the case (at least now but who knows the future). Then `subprocess.Popen()` can be used to run `shutdown.exe` with its full path.

`subprocess.Popen()` offers `subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW` for calling `CreateProcess` with the Process Creation Flag `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` set in `dwCreationFlags` for not opening a new console window for the Windows console application `shutdown.exe`.