# tkinter messagebox which turns your computer off

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to shut down the computer when the yes button of messagebox is clicked, but my code doesn't work somehow, and I don't know where is the problem

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

res = messagebox.askquestion("Prezentácia bez názvu.pptx", "Failed to load. Do you wish to continue? ")

def shutdown():
    return os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")

def askMe():
    if res == 'yes':
        command=shutdown
    if res == 'no':
        command=shutdown
```

Comment: . [this should answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039845/how-to-shutdown-a-computer-using-python)

Comment: I suggest, for the safety of your schooling years, avoid trolling your teachers like this. Also you aren't calling `askMe` or `shutdown`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don`t need to use return in shutdown function, just remove the return keyword and
in askMe function you can simply call shutdown function. In the last you have to call askMe function.

Comment: yeah this works <3

Answer (score 0):

yeah the code works now

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

res = messagebox.askquestion("Prezentácia bez názvu.pptx", "Failed to load. Do you wish to continue? ")

if res == 'yes':
    os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
else:
    os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
```