# I need to get python to reboot my raspberry pi once a day

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to get python to reboot my raspberry pi once a day. I have no code to show for what I have tried. I'm sure someone here can tell me how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [restart local computer from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629131/restart-local-computer-from-python)

Comment: Sorry "bantix" but this is a raspberry pi not a windows device that I'm using. Thanks for tying though

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Have you done any research? A simple google search leads to plenty of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
os.system("reboot")
```

Look into cron jobs on the operating system of your choice to execute this regularly

[Execute a daily reboot on a raspberry pi](http://raspberry.tips/raspberrypi-einsteiger/cronjob-auf-dem-raspberry-pi-einrichten)

Go to shell, give the python script execution rights with `sudo chmod +rwx /path/to/script.py`

```
sudo su
nano /etc/crontab
```

Enter in the crontab file the following

```
@daily     root      /path/to/script.py
```

Comment: Great answer. Now can you tell me how to reboot it once a day with python script?

Comment: @UNKNOWN as I wrote this depends on your operating system.Which OS do you use? What you are looking for is a cron job

Comment: I use a raspberry pi  which operates from linux.